# Inconsistent question in Korean Visa form

Tags: visas, applications, south-korea

The Republic of Korea online visa application form has a section where it asks if you have used any other names.

[image]

However when we generate a PDF after filling out the form, this question changes to something different:

[image]

Now I have never been to Korea, however I want to answer this question as yes. But if I answer yes then it is a misleading answer.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

UPDATE:

I further checked and found more gaps in the web application form. It seems to be very ad-hoc. Also I noticed on the VFS page that minor corrections on page are allowed, which indicates that they don't expect the web form info to be perfect.

So I will be filling out the web form keeping the PDF as a source of truth.

Comment: If the first image is a Web page, perhaps try altering size/zoom to see if there is any un-displayed text after "_alias, etc.)_". Or try selecting that text and/or using the browser's developer tools to inspect it.

Comment: If you have never been to Korea, how could you answer "Have you ever used any other names to enter or depart Korea?" with Yes? the answer must be No.

Comment: If the PDF is what you actually submit, answer the questions that it asks.

Answer (score 1):

The [.pdf application form](https://overseas.mofa.go.kr/upload/cntnts/ca-en/Application_for_VISA.pdf) on the Canadian Embassy website (non-fillable) supports your Korean language translation with their bilingual form:

[image]

I think it's fairly clear what they are after.

Interesting that the Korean language machine translates as "have you.." and the English refers to "has the applicant .. ".

Comment: Why do you assume it is a language machine translation?

Comment: @EarlGrey No assumptions. I did a machine translation on the Korean in the form above and compared English to Korean.